# How to create a POJO class from OpenAPI (Swagger)?

Tags: swagger, pojo, swagger-2.0

How can I create a POJO class for the following OpenAPI (Swagger) definition?

```yaml
paths:
  /execute:
    post:
      summary: 'Execute the web service and get a response synchronously'
      operationId: execute
      parameters:
        - in: body
          name: 'body'
          description: 'Execution request'
          schema:
            $ref: '#/definitions/ExecutionRequest'
        - in: query
          name: 'api-version'
          description: 'the version of the backend API'
          required: true
          type: number
          default: 2.0
        - in: query
          name: 'format'
          description: 'the format of the backend API'
          required: true
          type: string
          default: "swagger"
      responses:
        '200':
          description: Execution results
          schema:
            $ref: '#/definitions/ExecutionResults'
      security:
        - api_key: []
```